# Does Scala have an equivalent of F#'s "type of"?

Tags: scala, f#

An example of type declaration in F#:

```
type ActiveCartData = { UnpaidItems: string list }
type PaidCartData = { PaidItems: string list; Payment: float }

type ShoppingCart = 
    | EmptyCart  // no data
    | ActiveCart of ActiveCartData
    | PaidCart of PaidCartData
```

How could we do something similar in Scala using `trait` and `case class` and/or `case object`?

A start:

```
trait ShoppingCart
case object EmptyCart extends ShoppingCart
case object ActiveCart extends ShoppingCart
case object PaidCart extends ShoppingCart
```

But how to make the relationship with the data holder types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for `case classes` instead of `case objects`. They can wrap data:

```
sealed trait ShoppingCart
case object EmptyCart extends ShoppingCart
case class ActiveCart(unpaidItems: Seq[String]) extends ShoppingCart
case class PaidCart(paidItems: Seq[String], payment: Float) extends ShoppingCart
```

or (if you want to keep these holder data types, which I would probably not do unless they are very complex)

```
sealed trait ShoppingCart
case object EmptyCart extends ShoppingCart
case class ActiveCart(unpaidItems: ActiveCartData) extends ShoppingCart
case class PaidCart(paidItems: PaidCartData) extends ShoppingCart
```

Comment: Yes, I was expecting `case class`. I just wanted to be sure there wasn't something like a type alias (excluding Scala's `type` keyword). Thanks!